# regex email pattern in a negate way

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-negation

I was working around some regex pattern

I have a variable,

```
var url = "last_name=Ahuja&something@test.com";
```

The url contains emailId. I have a regex pattern to check if the variable contains emailId.

```
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

My requirement is:
I want exact negate(opposite) of the above pattern. Like, My condition should be false if the url contains email pattern.
I mean the regex pattern should be in that way.

Can somebody please help me on this.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: The two answers (currently) on this question will both claim that _**my**_ actual, perfectly valid email address is _not valid_. Read Hackerman's link and heed its warnings. People try to use a regex that is _far too simple_ when matching email, and there's no point doing it anyway since you should send a confirmation email to the address entered.

Comment: The link posted by @Hackerman no longer works, the new location seems to be here: https://david-gilbertson.medium.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643

Answer (score 1):

Using a negative lookahead you can check if the string does not have an email at the beginning, which mimics the behavior you want since your regex had start and end anchors.

`^(?!([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+).*$`

But if you wanted to make sure there was no valid email anywhere in the line, you could modify this a little.

`^((?!([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+).)*$`

See an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/3390376)

But you should just do this in code like Jonathan suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of negating your regex, you can test whether it matches.

```
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
var url = "last_name=Ahuja&something@test.com";

if(-1 === url.search(filter))
{
    alert("Didn't find it");
}
else
{
    alert("Found it");
}
```